# readTypedList of Abstract Parcelable Class - Android

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a Abstract Class called "Parent" and two Derived class of Parent Class says "Child1", "Child2"

I have implemented the Parent Class as Parcelable.

on writeToParcel i have wrote the List using writeTypedList(Items).

But while reading i cannot use readTypedList(List list, Parcelable.Creator c) to read the List since c is not known.

Can u please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parcelable inheritance: abstract class - Which CREATOR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567735/parcelable-inheritance-abstract-class-which-creator)