# Parcel/un-parcel list of instances from base generic class

Tags: android, generics, parcelable, parcel

I have a base generic abstract class, lets call it `Base<T>` class.

This class extended by few subclass, with different types for `T mData`.
Let's say that I have `class Sub1 extends Base<byte []>` and `class Sub2 extends Base<Object>`.

In addition, I have a instancesList with type of `List<Base<T>>`, compounded from instances of `Sub1` and `Sub2`.

1. How can I parcel/un-parcel this list as a whole?
2. Where should I implement the `Parcelable` interface? Where does the `CREATOR` goes, if any?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you implement the reader (`CREATOR`) and the writer in the concrete classes, not in the abstract class.

When an instance of a concrete class is written to the `Parcel`, the name of the concrete class is also automatically written to the `Parcel`. When this is unparceled, the name of the concrete class is read, and the appropriate `CREATOR` is called to create a new instance of that concrete class.

There are some situations where you need to implement the reader and writer in the abstract class. In that case
see [Parcelable inheritance: abstract class - Which CREATOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567735/parcelable-inheritance-abstract-class-which-creator) for more complex solutions.